# iPhone SDK: Uploading pictures to TwitPic.com

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way I can upload a selected image to TwitPic.com and get the images page URL?

Here is the API page for TwitPic.com:

http://twitpic.com/api.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API indicates it returns the URI in a XML document. You can use an [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to post the image data, and use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get the resulting URL.